# web2py - how to inject html

Tags: python, web2py

i used rows.xml() to generate html output. i want to know how to add html codes to this generated html page e.g: "add logo, link css file,.. etc"

`rows=db(db.member.membership_id==request.args[0]).select(db.member.membership_id
                                                  ,db.member.first_name,db.member.middle_name
                                                  ,db.member.last_name)
     return rows.xml()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many HTML helpers you can use, for example:

```
html_code = A('<click>', rows.xml(), _href='http://mylink')
html_code = B('Results:', rows.xml(), _class='results', _id=1)
html_page = HTML(BODY(B('Results:', rows.xml(), _class='results', _id=1)))
```

and so on.

You can even create a whole table automatically:

```
table = SQLTABLE(rows, orderby=True, _width="100%")
```

and then pick it apart to insert links or modify its elements.

It is very powerful and normally you don't have to bother writing the actual HTML yourself. [Here is the cheatsheet](http://www.web2py.com/examples/static/web2py_cheatsheet.pdf), or you can check directly on the [website documentation](http://www.web2py.com/examples/default/docs).

---

Edit: Just to make sure, you don't actually need to generate the whole HTML page, it is easier to let web2py insert your response in a template that has the same name as your controller (or force a particular template with `response.view = 'template.html'`. The documentation tutorial will explain that better and in further details.

In a few words, if you are implementing the function `index`, you could either return a string (the whole page HTML, which seems to be what you are heading for), or a dictionary to use templates.

In the first case, just code your function like this:

```
def index():
    # ... code to extract the rows
    return HTML(BODY(B('Results:', rows.xml(), _class='results', _id=1))).xml()
```

Otherwise, write an html template in views/*controller*/index.html (or another file if you insert the `response.view=...` in your function, to re-use the same template), which could be like this:

```
<html><head></head>
  <body>
    {{=message}}
  </body>
</html>
```

and return a dictionary:

```
def index():
    # ... code to extract the rows
    html = B('Results:', rows.xml(), _class='results', _id=1)
    return dict(message=html)
```

Comment: Thanks for your help.

after adding the previous lines to my function what to write at the return of function "instead of return rows.xml() to display a html page"

Comment: You're welcome. I've just added a bit for the whole page (which was the original question), check the Edit: remark though.

Comment: i am not understand how 
 >response.view = 'template.html' can ghelp me to fix my problem. i checked the document and i dont understand.

Thanks

Comment: i tried the first line "return HTML(BODY(B('Results:', rows.xml(), _class='results', _id=1)))
" and it displayed html tages into generated html page.

The second one displayed an error "NameError: global name 'ODY' is not defined" i removed it and the same html tages displayed. i dont know why?

Comment: I've never tried to return the whole HTML code, but I suppose it's necessary to extract the xml first, so maybe something along `return HTML(...).xml()` is the correct way to do that.

Comment: The 'ODY' was a typo (I'm especially good at them today) :-) Hopefully fixed the post.

Answer (score 0):

Just prepend/append it to the string that `rows.xml()` returns:

```
html = '<html><head>...</head><body>' + rows.xml() + '</body></html>'
```

Comment: i wrote this line: 
   data = "<html><body>"+rows.xml+"</body></html>" and,
it displayed the following error: 
   'TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'instancemethod' objects'

Comment: Oops... I forgot the "()" after xml. Fixed.

Comment: just noted that html = '<html><head>...</head><body>' + rows.xml() + '</body></html>' doestn't work in python 3.6