# web2py - display a SQL query in a form

Tags: python, web2py

i have a SQL query

```
family_members = db(\
    db.member.parent_membership_id==parent_id.membership_id\
    ).select(\
    db.member.first_name, db.member.parent_membership_id)
```

I want to display "family_members" as a table in my form.

How can i do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In view:

```
{{=family_members}}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can follow the example I've shown you [in a previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1550368/web2py-how-to-inject-html/1550413#1550413).

Make sure to also check the documentation on the [web2py website](http://www.web2py.com/examples/default/docs), seeing the work you are doing with this framework I would recommend to buy the web2py official manual which is really not expensive and will save you a lot of precious time. You can also read it online from the link I gave you, or download a few free chapters.

Basically you have two options,

- use the `SQLTABLE`
- if you want further control on the table, you can transform the result given by the above option (it's a class you can use to modify the contents), or create it entirely on your own with the HTML helpers (`TABLE` and so on, from the `gluon` library).

To illustrate that a little bit:

```
family_members = db(...).select(...) # your rows construct
table = SQLTABLE(family_members, orderby=True, _class='sortable', _width="100%")
```

If you want to add a column, for example:

```
table[0][0].append(TH("details"))
for i, value in enumerate(table[1]):
    table[1][i].append(TD("line %d" % i, _align="center"))
```